# Knockout foreach with list of functions

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm having trouble using a foreach binding over a list of functions.  I want the inner context to be the function itself, but instead, the context is bound to the result of invoking the function.  Here's a simple example that illustrates this:   ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dq4ec706/2/))

JS:

```
ko.applyBindings({
    list: [
        function() {
            return "hodor";
        }
    ]
});
```

HTML:

```
<!-- ko foreach: list -->
<span data-bind="text: typeof $data"></span>
<span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
<br />
<!-- /ko -->
```

Output is: "string foo" but I would like it to be "function function () { return "foo"; }"

As a workaround I can do `$parent.list[$index()]`, but that's really ugly, and I'd like to avoid that syntax, if possible.

(For explanation in my real usage, these aren't simple functions but functions that I've attached extra properties to that I want to reference, but I can't reference them because knockout is invoking them)

EDIT:

It appears that there's a KO version issue here.  Before 3.0, it wasn't an issue, the context was always bound to the function not the value.  On 3.0, using `$rawData` would give the function, not that value, but on 3.2, it doesn't, which is what I'm trying to use.

I've updated the above fiddle to use 3.2, and here's a fiddle for each version, including `$rawData` (except in 2.3 where $rawData doesn't exist)

[Knockout 2.3 fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9asf9ww/1/): `$rawData` not needed

[Knockout 3.0 fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/366rokq4/2/): `$rawData` works

[Knockout 3.2 fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dq4ec706/2/): `$rawData` doesn't work.

Could this be a KO 3.2 bug?

Comment: I'm sure it's some mix up with how it assumes a function is going to be an observable and so invokes it. One possible work around might be to just wrap your functions in another function like this: http://jsfiddle.net/dq4ec706/3/ but that seems really, really silly. It makes `$data` work on both 3.0 and 3.2, but not in 2.3.

Comment: Yeah, I'd rather use the `$parent.list[$index()]` workaround, which always works, than wrap my functions again, personally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this was a bug in KO 3.0.

In < 2.3 this was a missing feature. Because without the `$rawData` you weren't able to work with arrays containing observablez `[ko.observable(1), ko.observable(2)]`.

In 3.0 `$rawData` was introduced but it was buggy. Which was fixed in 3.1 https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/1206.

So this the correct behavior as summarized by [daedalus28](https://github.com/daedalus28) in the above linked issue:

> `$rawData` should be the return value if it's a function but not an observable. If it's an observable (or the result of the function is an observable), it should be unwrapped into `$data` and not `$rawData` - `$rawData` should retain the actual observable (the result of the function)

So currently your use case is not supported by KO.

So you have to use on `$parent.list[$index()]` or don't directly put your functions into the array.

Wrap them to observables

```
 list: [
        ko.observable(function() {
            return "foo";   
        }),
        ko.observable(function() {
            return "bar";
        }),
        ko.observable(function() {
            return "hodor";
        })
    ]
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ur7k9hn/).

or put them on some dummy objects:

```
list: [
    {bar: function() {
        return "foo";   
    }},
    {bar: function() {
        return "bar";
    }},
    {bar: function() {
        return "hodor";
    }}
]
```

And you write:

```
<span data-bind="text: bar"></span>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3pcm0nr7/).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow their logic of why functions should always be unwrapped for me, while observables aren't; but I suppose I can take it up on the issue you posted if I want.   Thanks for the answer!